# Doing the levels for an Android game: how to shuffle the questions from a given range in my database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, shuffle

I'm trying to create a simple math quiz game that has a level system. I'm using an SQLite database. I just want to know how to shuffle the first 5 entry questions in my database when I click the level 1 and the 6-10 entry question if I click the level 2.

**Here is my code for `MainmenuActivity.java`:**

```
public class MainmenuActivity extends Activity { 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void submit(View v)
{
    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainmenuActivity.this);
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(1,"1+1=?","2","3","4","5");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(2,"3+1","4","5","6","7");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(3,"6+4=?","10","20","30","40");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(4,"1+4?","5","11","10","9");
    entry.close();


    Intent i = new Intent(MainmenuActivity.this, game.class);
    startActivity(i);
} 
public void level2(View v){

    DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(MainmenuActivity.this);
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(5,"7+1?","8","2","5","4");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(6,"9+3?","12","13","11","10");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(7,"10+1?","11"," 2","13","5");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(8,"7+5=?","12","13","14","15");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(9,"15+1?","16","18","6","17");
    entry.close();
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(10,"6+12?","18","12","22","15");
    entry.close();

    Intent i = new Intent(MainmenuActivity.this, game.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

**My code in the `game.java`:**

```
//this is for displaying the questions


public class game extends Activity { 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    b[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Questions();
}
public void Questions()
{
    DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(game.this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    Cursor CR = mDbHelper.getInformation(mDbHelper);
    CR.moveToFirst();
    x=rand.nextInt(101-1)+1;
    y=rand.nextInt(5-1)+1;
    for (z=0;z<76;z++)
    {
        if (x==finishedquestions[z])
        {
            x=rand.nextInt(101-1)+1;
            z=0;
        }
    }
    do{
        if (x.equals(CR.getInt(0)))
        {
            question = CR.getString(1);
            t.setText(CR.getString(1));
            right=CR.getString(2);
            wrong1=CR.getString(3);
            wrong2=CR.getString(4);
            wrong3=CR.getString(5);
            b[y].setText(right);

            if (y==1)
            {
                b[2].setText(wrong1);
                b[3].setText(wrong2);
                b[4].setText(wrong3);
            }else if (y==2)
            {
                b[1].setText(wrong1);
                b[3].setText(wrong2);
                b[4].setText(wrong3);
            }else if (y==3)
            {
                b[2].setText(wrong1);
                b[1].setText(wrong2);
                b[4].setText(wrong3);
            }else if (y==4)
            {
                b[2].setText(wrong1);
                b[3].setText(wrong2);
                b[1].setText(wrong3);
            }
        }
    }while(CR.moveToNext());
    finishedquestions[ctrquestions]=x;
    ctrquestions++;
}
```

}

Comment: you can choose random number from the given range. while loading next question do the same, but make sure that you have not used that no before

Answer (score 0):

Your question has little to do with android, I think.

If I understand correctly, you are asking: how do I generate a random permutation of the values 1 to n ?

(In other words, given questions 1 to 5, how do I "shuffle" them? Note that if you wanted q 6 to 10, the procedure is the same and then you just add and offset of 5)

There are a number of algorithms to generate uniformly distributed random permutations. A simple one is the one called [Knuth shuffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation#Knuth_shuffles).